# how to convert text to image in wordpress and create thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress, image, text

hi i have a wordpress at lesprenoms.quebec it's listing the name of people with a short description.

if you take a look at this post:
http://lesprenoms.quebec/qeZN30e9

it's a simple div with image as background with text on top and an other image at the bottom what i want is that wordpress generate all the thumbnail i want and also the one for facebook witch is 750*394px crop top when i hit publish or like save the draft and else and that it get update if i change the text on top of the image.

some will tell me to do this trough photoshop and else witch i already did for the 170 other image but i think i can made template, then just upload the image and just add my text that all trough the website without having to fire photoshop witch can be really usefull as if i'm on other computer and else...

so i know there a way to do this in php with maybe imagefttext or something like that. All the thing is wrap in a div so maybe a function that get all the text + image between the first  and the last  could be really nice and neat.

so if someone can help cause i really need your help guy...

Comment: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ is something I've used repeatedly for auto thumbs but I believe it's w/in the screen window and your stuff looks longer

Comment: if you tell me how to implement it to create the thumbnail maybe with that it will work:

`html2canvas(div#prenoms, {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {
    div#prenoms.appendChild(canvas);
  },
  allowTaint: true,
  width: 100%,
  height: 100%,
  taintTest: true
});`

if you want to @TomWoodward